# Bootstrap 5 Tabs Will not toggle content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using the example that the BS 5 doc has on creating a simple tabs ui but it is does not change the content when clicking on the different tabs. What am I missing? It works on the BS 5 demo and I'm using the exact code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/zYmjzVa?editors=1000).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're upgrading this code from an old version of Bootstrap.

In Bootstrap 5.2.3 you need to use `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`. See: [Migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#javascript).

Change it and whoops it works.